# Multiple selectors with same child class?

Tags: jquery

How can i stack id names?

```
$("#account-edit .input-group.date, #account-create .input-group.date, #group-edit .input-group.date").datepicker({
.....
});
```

Something like this:

```
$("#account-edit, #account-create, #group-edit", ".input-group.date").datepicker({
    .....
    });
```

Comment: Why wouldn't just `$(".input-group.date")` be sufficient?

Answer (score 3):

`$("#account-edit, #account-create, #group-edit").find('.input-group.date')` is what you're looking for!